# jQuery UI form stopped working, with no known changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, accordion

I'm having trouble with a previously working jQuery UI product order form on pages such as http://deadlynightshades.com/custom/squared/eddie

This is a jQuery UI Accordion, Tabs, and Buttons with an html form. All the scripts and stylesheets appear to be properly linked.

The accordion doesn't seem to be establishing itself properly anymore. The styling classes are applied, but the expand and contract behavior does not respond.

The only script I wrote myself is at http://deadlynightshades.com/Frontend/Capacitor/Scripts/Deadly.js
**Can anyone tell me if it has errors?** Again, it used to work, for months, until a few days ago.

The jQuery UI elements are established in the Deadly.js script:

```
//  Establish jQuery-UI controls
$("#Tabs").tabs();
$("input:submit").button();
$("a.addtocart").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-cart" }});
$("#Accordion").accordion();
```

If the line initializing the accordion is moved, then the part of the script remaining above the command will function. When the accordion is established near the top of the script, nothing that follows works as expected. The accordion() broke, as far as I can tell.

Another symptom has to do with foxycart. When a product is added to the shopping cart, the cart should display in a lightbox. For some reason, it has started displaying as a standalone page.

I will answer any requests for more info. I'm at a loss. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show the <script> and <link> tags you are using for jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: Just saw your request. The jQuery link was to the latest version provided by google. I thought being up with the latest with that would be for the best. But as you suspected, a version change to 1.9 from 1.8 affected my site unexpectely. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery from google. It's possible that your site was designed with an older version of jQuery in mind and you were updated to 1.9.0 by the link you use.

Comment: Thanks! I knew jQuery Ui hadd updated toa 1.9, and I specifically made sure to link to the version I developed with. I did not know jQuery itself had updated, with some backwards compatability problems, also to vversion 1.9! I link now to the http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js instead of the "latest" I was getting from google. I did not expect them to break things. It is working! Thanks for the spot, nice! I'll see if I can mark yours as the answer. Very helpful, thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:220
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://deadlynightshades.com/Frontend/Capacitor/Images/Eggplant/ui-bg_flat_30_3d3644_40x100.png
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js:24
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js:22
```

Comment: How'd you all discover these errors? Thanks. Also, I think my question establishes there are errors in loading the page. Where and what is the cause of these errors. The info in the answer suggests I might disble my image-slider, see if that removes some conflict.Thanks